# nohup ./startup & Permission Denied

Tags: c++, compilation, nohup

I successfully compiled a MUD source code, and it says in the instructions to start up the server using

```
nohup ./startup &
```

although when I do this it gives me this error:

```
$ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
nohup: failed to run command `./startup': Permission denied
```

I have looked all over the internet to find the answer. A few of them said to put my cygwin directory in the root folder (I am using windows 7) and its directory is C:\cygwin

so thats not a problem.. Can anyone help me with this please??

Comment: are you sure startup is in the current directory? Also, the tags are all inappropriate.

Comment: Yes the startup file is in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try `chmod +x startup`, maybe your `startup` file is not executable.

Answer (score 0):

From "[man nohup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/nohup.html)":

> If the standard output is a terminal, all output written by the named
>   utility to its standard output shall be appended to the end of the
>   file nohup.out in the current directory. If nohup.out cannot be
>   created or opened for appending, the output shall be appended to the
>   end of the file nohup.out in the directory specified by the HOME
>   environment variable. If neither file can be created or opened for
>   appending, utility shall not be invoked. If a file is created, the
>   file's permission bits shall be set to S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR.

My guess is that since "sh -c" doesn't start a login shell, it is inheriting the environment of the invoking shell, including the HOME  environment variable, and is trying to open it there. So I would check the permissions of both your current directory and `$HOME`. You can try to `touch test.txt` in current directory or `$HOME` to see if you can perform that command.

Comment: Ok is there a way i can start the startup script without using the terminal then?

Comment: You can try starting it up without the `nohup`. If your terminal times out after a long period of inactivity, however, then the process may be terminated after a period of time. At least this will help isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As staticx writes, check the permissions of the directory (and the user) - and the executable.

Instead of using `nohup`:

- check if `nohup` is needed at all, try `./startup </dev/null >mud.out 2>mud.err &`, then close the terminal window and check if it is running
- or just run `./startup` in a `screen` session and detach it (`<ctrl>+<a>,<d>`)